# Parsing Facebook's Signed Request in Clojure

Tags: facebook, clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

I'm trying to build a website with Luminus in order to learn a bit of Clojure. I've had years of imperative experience but only now getting into functional programming. Right now, I'm trying to [process a signed_request object from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/#parsingsr).

According to the site I have to:

1. Split a string on a period (".") and get a vector of 2 strings.
2. Take the first of those strings, decode it w/ base64 and compare with a secret.
3. Take the second of those strings, decode it w/ base64 and decode again with JSON.

This is really straight-forward if I was doing it in an imperative language, but I am clueless when it comes to a functional approach. Right now I've only gotten as far as finding out how to split the string into a vector of 2 strings:

```
(defn parse-request [signed_request]
  ((clojure.string/split signed_request #"\.")
    ))

(defn redirect-page [signed_request]
  (layout/render "redirect.html"
                 {:parsed_request parse-request(signed_request)}))

(defroutes home-routes
  (GET "/" [] (home-page))
  (POST "/redirect" [signed_request] (redirect-page signed_request)))
```

redirect-page is run when the server receives the POST request, and then it takes the signed_request and passes it into the parse-request function. What is the functional way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic answer to your question is that functional programming is more about input and output (think of a mathematical function), whereas imperative programming tends to be more about side effects and mutable data. Instead of thinking, "what do I need to *do*?", think, "what kind of data structure is my goal, and how do I *define* it?" You can have side effects too (like printing), but generally you are writing pure functions that take arguments and return something.

[Destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) is an invaluable tool in Clojure, and it would come in handy here. You want to split a string into two strings using `clojure.string/split`, and then do something with one of the strings and something else with the other. You could use a `let` binding to assign names to each string, like this:

```
(let [[str1 str2] (clojure.string/split signed-request #"\.")]
  (do-stuff-with-str1-and-str2))
```

I'm not too familiar with this specific problem, but based on the 3 steps you listed, it sounds like you will be getting 2 results, one from each string. So, maybe you should focus on writing a function that returns a vector containing the 2 results, like this:

```
(defn process-signed-request [signed-request]
  (let [[str1 str2] (clojure.string/split signed-request #"\.")]
    [(compare-fn (decode-with-base-64 str1) secret)
     (decode-with-json (decode-with-base-64 str2))]))
```

Note that the above is partially pseudocode -- you will need to replace `compare-fn`, `decode-with-base-64`, `decode-with-json`, and `secret` with the actual code representing these things -- that, or you can leave it as-is and just implement the functions so that `compare-fn`, `decode-with-base-64` and `decode-with-json` refer to actual functions that you write. This is a common approach in functional programming -- write a short higher-level function that defines the solution to the problem, and then go back and write the helper functions that it uses.

By the way, there are a couple of other ways you can write the `(decode-with-json (decode-with-base-64 str2))` part:

1. `((comp decode-with-json decode-with-base-64) str2)`
2. `(-> str2 decode-with-base-64 decode-with-json)`

I often find the second approach, using a threading macro (`->` or `->>`) helpful when I know the sequence of things that I need to do with an object, and I want the code to read intuitively. I find it easier to read, like "take `str2`, decode it with base 64, and then decode it again with JSON."

Also, this is just a nitpicky thing, but pay attention to the order of parentheses when you're coding in Clojure. The way you have your code now, the parentheses should look like this:

```
(defn parse-request [signed_request]
  (clojure.string/split signed_request #"\."))

(defn redirect-page [signed_request]
  (layout/render "redirect.html"
                 {:parsed_request (parse-request signed_request)}))
```

If you have a lot of imperative experience, you're probably so ingrained in the `fn(x)` syntax that you accidentally type that instead of the `(fn x)` Lisp syntax that Clojure uses.

And while I'm nitpicking, it's idiomatic in Clojure to use hyphens instead of underscores for symbol naming. So, I would rename `signed_request` and `:parsed_request` to `signed-request` and `:parsed-request`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It looks like this is going to take up a lot more time than I thought, maybe I should refrain from doing this during exam time, haha.

Comment: No prob :) If you want to get more into functional programming, think about reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com). It's a book on Haskell, not Clojure, but it's a great introduction to functional programming that starts from square 1. I actually learned a little Haskell first before I learned Clojure, and it made the FP concepts a lot easier to understand.